# Detecting Special Characters with Regular Expression in python?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

df

```
   Name
0  @#
1  R@#
2  ghj@#
3  Ray
4  *@+
5  Jack
6  Sara123#
7  ( 1234. )
8  Benjamin k 123
9  _
10 _!@#_
11 _#_&@+-
12 56#@!
```

Output:

```
 Bad_Name
0  @#
1  *@+
2  _
3  _!@#_
4  _#_&@+-
```

I need to detect the special character through regular expression. If a string contains any alphabet or Number then that string is valid else it will consider as bad string.
I was using '^\W*$' RE, everything was working fine except when the string contains '_'( underscore) it is not treating as Bad String.

Comment: Just use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead of `\w` to exclude `_` and `-`

Comment: I did this for replacing values with Null. df.replace({"[A-Za-z0-9]":np.nan}, regex= True) but it is not working

Comment: Instead of `^\W*$` use `^[\W_]+$` that means non word character or underscore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas.Series.str.contains`:

```
df[~df['Name'].str.contains('[a-z0-9]', False)]
```

Output:

```
       Name
0        @#
4       *@+
9         _
10    _!@#_
11  _#_&@+-
```

Comment: I did this for replacing values with Null. df.replace({"[A-Za-z0-9]":np.nan}, regex= True) but it is not working

Comment: You can't use `dict` and `regex`. Try `df.replace("[A-Za-z0-9]", np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: It will replace with null wherever pattern matches. I need to make null only those values where there is pure special characters ( not contain any number or alphabets).